# Jenkins zip debug and release APKs and want to do archiveArtifacts

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-groovy, cicd

in my project we have 2 build variants (assume) paidA & paidB. assemble the app will generate 4 apks which are (paidA debug and release) and (paidB Debug and release).
I need to artifact all these four apks. I tried with the following code but it fails

```
sh "zip -r builds.zip . -i builds"
sh "cd ${env.WORKSPACE}"
echo "${env.WORKSPACE}"
archiveArtifacts artifacts: "builds.zip", onlyIfSuccessful: true
```

Kindly advice a bit to get rid off this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working solution. Kindly make sure the path as per your project.

```
 stage('Artifact') {
  steps {
   script {
     sh "mkdir -p ${env.WORKSPACE}/builds"
            
     sh "cp app/build/outputs/apk/*/*/*.apk ${env.WORKSPACE}/builds"

     sh "cd ${env.WORKSPACE}/builds"

     zip zipFile: 'apks.zip', archive: false, dir: 
     "${env.WORKSPACE}/builds"
            
     archiveArtifacts artifacts: '${env.WORKSPACE}/builds, apks.zip', 
      onlyIfSuccessful: true
   }
  }
}
```